# Is webpack libraryTarget 'umd' supposed to work with ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to distribute a node based library with webpack.
I've seen that most of js libraries around can be used both with:

commonJs syntax

`const lib = require('library')`

or ES6 syntax

`import * as lib from "library"`

I have followed [this tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) and my final webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'sepa.js',
        library: 'sepajs',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this"
    }
};
```

although on the browser this import statement results in an empty module:

```
  import * as SepaJs from "./sepa.js"
```

Is webpack suppose to export a commonJs based library to ES6 module library?
Should I have to transcompile it with babel? Can I have one bundle file with both module solution?

Comment: You want to bundle FROM CommonJS TO UMD, correct?

Comment: FROM CommonJS to ES6 module library. I don't know if UMD works with ES6 module system. I mean, can I import a UMD library using `import * as foo from "./foo.js"`?

Comment: No, an UMD module is not an ES6 module - it can't be *that* universal unfortunately, as the ES6 module requires special syntax that would be a parse error elsewhere.